# Flex: Menu/Submenu navigation for iPad

Tags: apache-flex, ipad, mobile, menu, navigation

I just finished creating a large online flex app with 43 different screens. I am using a mx:MenuBar with four main menus and a couple of submenus to navigate between these screens. I am now trying to convert this into a iPad app as well, but the mx:MenuBar does not appear to be supported in mobile flex. Is there any way I can replicate this sort of navigation system in mobile flex? The user needs to be able to move between any of these pages at any time, and 43 tabs will obviously not work!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 43 tabs will obviously not work. You could make a scrollable tab bar, but from a usability point of view, I'd recommend against such a thing.

How about some sort of grouping the 43 tabs and then use a ButtonBar to create your tabs? To access sub-tabs, you could use a Callout. The ButtonBar would then be linked to your ViewNavigator.

Comment: Thanks - the button bar with callouts was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can use viewNavigator in flex mobile to achieve this, In view navigator  push and pop views functions will allow you to navigate between views, You can refer this [link](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/View+and+ViewNavigator), and also [this one](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-7fff.html) to get a basic idea about view navigators.

Comment: That is one option, but it would be nice if the user could have some sort of menu on the top of every page, so they can go directly from one page to another, instead of having to keeping going back and forwards, which I think would have to happen with a view navigator.

Answer (score 0):

For something similiar to this I am using an UIPopover. Just like in this [SpliView-example](https://mikebluestein.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/using-a-uisplitviewcontroller-to-create-a-master-detail-ipad-app-with-monotouch/) but I am just using the toolbar with the button.

If you can categorize your screens, you could use 4-5 buttons with your correspondending screens in the tableview.